# How to solve this function in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was writing a python program where I enter two parameters: one is a list of strings and the second is a list of lists.
I want to return a new list of dictories which can be explained by this example:

> Input: dic_list_gen(["administered_janssen", "administered_unk_manuf", "date", "administered_pfizer", "location"], [[481366, "2021-02-15T00:00:00.000", "LA", 668, 0], ["NV", 0, 805475, "2021-04-06T00:00:00.000", 37820], [4549654, "AZ", 13413, "2021-09-28T00:00:00.000", 288209], [288865, "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000", 4283531, 7149, "OH"], ["2021-06-21T00:00:00.000", 2984, 3283082, 213637, "CO"], ["2021-06-04T00:00:00.000", 1468455, 99716, "AL", 0], ["DC", 17414, 275181, "2021-04-14T00:00:00.000", 0]])

> Expected Output: [{"administered_janssen": 481366, "administered_unk_manuf": "2021-02-15T00:00:00.000", "date": "LA", "administered_pfizer": 668, "location": 0}, {"administered_janssen": "NV", "administered_unk_manuf": 0, "date": 805475, "administered_pfizer": "2021-04-06T00:00:00.000", "location": 37820}, {"administered_janssen": 4549654, "administered_unk_manuf": "AZ", "date": 13413, "administered_pfizer": "2021-09-28T00:00:00.000", "location": 288209}, {"administered_janssen": 288865, "administered_unk_manuf": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000", "date": 4283531, "administered_pfizer": 7149, "location": "OH"}, {"administered_janssen": "2021-06-21T00:00:00.000", "administered_unk_manuf": 2984, "date": 3283082, "administered_pfizer": 213637, "location": "CO"}, {"administered_janssen": "2021-06-04T00:00:00.000", "administered_unk_manuf": 1468455, "date": 99716, "administered_pfizer": "AL", "location": 0}, {"administered_janssen": "DC", "administered_unk_manuf": 17414, "date": 275181, "administered_pfizer": "2021-04-14T00:00:00.000", "location": 0}]

> My Output: [{'administered_janssen': 'DC', 'administered_unk_manuf': 17414, 'date': 275181, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-04-14T00:00:00.000', 'location': 0}, {'administered_janssen': 'DC', 'administered_unk_manuf': 17414, 'date': 275181, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-04-14T00:00:00.000', 'location': 0}, {'administered_janssen': 'DC', 'administered_unk_manuf': 17414, 'date': 275181, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-04-14T00:00:00.000', 'location': 0}, {'administered_janssen': 'DC', 'administered_unk_manuf': 17414, 'date': 275181, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-04-14T00:00:00.000', 'location': 0}, {'administered_janssen': 'DC', 'administered_unk_manuf': 17414, 'date': 275181, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-04-14T00:00:00.000', 'location': 0}, {'administered_janssen': 'DC', 'administered_unk_manuf': 17414, 'date': 275181, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-04-14T00:00:00.000', 'location': 0}, {'administered_janssen': 'DC', 'administered_unk_manuf': 17414, 'date': 275181, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-04-14T00:00:00.000', 'location': 0}]

My Code:

```
def dic_list_gen(los,l):
  d = []
  k = {}
  i = 0
  for x in l:
    i = 0
    for r in los:
      k[r] = x[i]
      i = i+1
    d.append(k)

  return d
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341) If you can make this question more specific, please [edit] it. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Just `zip` the headers with each sublist and turn the result into a dict.

```
>>> def dic_list_gen(headers, data):
...     return [dict(zip(headers, i)) for i in data]
...
>>> dic_list_gen(["administered_janssen", "administered_unk_manuf", "date", "administered_pfizer", "location"], [[481366, "2021-02-15T00:00:00.000", "LA", 668, 0], ["NV", 0, 805475, "2021-04-06T00:00:00.000", 37820], [4549654, "AZ", 13413, "2021-09-28T00:00:00.000", 288209], [288865, "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000", 4283531, 7149, "OH"], ["2021-06-21T00:00:00.000", 2984, 3283082, 213637, "CO"], ["2021-06-04T00:00:00.000", 1468455, 99716, "AL", 0], ["DC", 17414, 275181, "2021-04-14T00:00:00.000", 0]])
[{'administered_janssen': 481366, 'administered_unk_manuf': '2021-02-15T00:00:00.000', 'date': 'LA', 'administered_pfizer': 668, 'location': 0}, {'administered_janssen': 'NV', 'administered_unk_manuf': 0, 'date': 805475, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-04-06T00:00:00.000', 'location': 37820}, {'administered_janssen': 4549654, 'administered_unk_manuf': 'AZ', 'date': 13413, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-09-28T00:00:00.000', 'location': 288209}, {'administered_janssen': 288865, 'administered_unk_manuf': '2021-04-26T00:00:00.000', 'date': 4283531, 'administered_pfizer': 7149, 'location': 'OH'}, {'administered_janssen': '2021-06-21T00:00:00.000', 'administered_unk_manuf': 2984, 'date': 3283082, 'administered_pfizer': 213637, 'location': 'CO'}, {'administered_janssen': '2021-06-04T00:00:00.000', 'administered_unk_manuf': 1468455, 'date': 99716, 'administered_pfizer': 'AL', 'location': 0}, {'administered_janssen': 'DC', 'administered_unk_manuf': 17414, 'date': 275181, 'administered_pfizer': '2021-04-14T00:00:00.000', 'location': 0}]
```